# When is the set $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis

$x_0 \in C[0,1]$, define $x_n = x_{n-1}(t^2)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. What is the condition for $x_0$ to make the set $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ equicontinuous?

Our professor said in the class that $x_0$ must be constant. I could not prove this directly. My idea is the following:

Since the family of the derivative is uniformly bounded implies equicontinuity. I calculated the derivatives:

$x_n(t)^{\prime}=nt^{n-1}x_0{\prime}(t^n)$. Then, if there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$x_0{\prime}(t^n)\leq \frac{M}{nt^{n-1}}$ for all $n$, then the set is equicontinuous.

Then, I stuck here. I do not know what to do next oor anything else. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x_n(t) = x_0(t^{2^n})$. Which is to say, I expect problems to happen at $t = 1$, since that's where the sequence $t^{2^n}$ has issues.

Indeed, if $a\in (0,1)$ such that $x_0(a)\neq x_0(1)$, then for any $\delta>0$, there is an $n$ such that $\sqrt[2^n]a\in (\delta, 1]$, which means $|x_n(t) - x_n(1)|\geq |x_0(a) - x_0(1)|$ for at least one $t\in (\delta, 1]$. This disproves equicontinuity at $1$ (pick $\varepsilon = |x_0(a) - x_0(1)|/2$, for instance).

Comment: In the part you said $\lvert x_n(t)−x_n(1) \rvert \ge \lvert x_0(1)−x_1(a) \rvert$, Why did you consider $x_1$ in the RHS of the inequality. Also, I could not see how this is obtained. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @MahmutEsatAkın The $x_1$ was a typo. And you know the definition of epicontinuous at a point (it starts with "for any $\varepsilon>0$"). Negate that, and you have the definition of not equicontinuous at a point (it starts with "there exists an $\varepsilon>0$"). Write it out if you have to. Then see that what I've written here is exactly a proof that $x_n$ is not equicontinuous at $1$, with a concrete $\varepsilon$ and everything. Perhaps not entirely in order (it's more ordered by how you would _look_ for a proof, rather than how a finished proof would look), but all the elements are there.

Comment: I understand the logic of your proof. I don't understand the specific inequality. I think you are asking too much from the equation. I mean, inequality is not necessary. Equality looks enough to me. This is why: $\lvert x_n(t)-x_n(1) \rvert = \lvert x_0(t^{2^n})-x_0(1) \rvert $ and for some $t \in ( \delta,1]$ this is equal to $\lvert x_0(a) -x_0(1) \rvert$. Now, we can take the epsilon you offer. Is this not correct?

Comment: @MahmutEsatAkın Sure, we can use equlity there instead of inequality. It's just that $\epsilon$-$\delta$ most often deals with inequalities, so it fits the theme better, aesthetically. But it's not really important which way you go.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, $x_n$ is a bounded sequence (as $\|x_n\|_{\infty}=\|x_0\|_{\infty}$), and it converges pointwise to the function $g$ mapping $t <1$ to $x_0(0)$ and $1$ to $x_0(1)$.

If $x_n$ is equicontinuous, it is precompact, so it must converge uniformly to $g$. In particular, $g$ must be continuous, so $x_0(1)=x_0(0)$. Besides, the $x_n$ all have the same maximum $\mu$, and since $g$ is the uniform limit of the $x_n$, $\mu$ is the maximum of $g$ so $\mu=x_0(0)$. Similarly, the minimum $m$ of $x_0$ is that of each $x_n$ so must be that of $g$ hence $m=x_0(0)=\mu$, therefore $x_0$ is constant.

Comment: I could not see the part you are saying it is obvious. Can you explain more?